# repeated data array .map () react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, arraylist, array.prototype.map

can someone tell me why my .map () array is returning the same data several times on thescreen? I would like to show it only once but I don't know why it is repeating,

Can someone help me?

React code below:

```
console.log('>>> [HistoricosAtendimento] props: ', props);
  const viewData = props.historicos || [];
  const convertToArray = Object.values(viewData);
  return (
    <>
      <SC.Container>
        <SC.Item>
          {convertToArray.map((item) => {
            console.log('convertToArray', convertToArray);
            return (
              <SC.Item key={item.protocolo}>
                <SC.Description>{item.textNotas}</SC.Description>
              </SC.Item>
            );
          })}
        </SC.Item>
```

Comment: can you create a demo on jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the outer wrapping component:

```js
     <SC.Container>
        // <SC.Item> <= remove
          {convertToArray.map((item) => {
            // console.log('convertToArray', convertToArray); // should move out of JSX
            return (
              <SC.Item key={item.protocolo}>
                <SC.Description>{item.textNotas}</SC.Description>
              </SC.Item>
            );
          })}
        // </SC.Item>  <= remove
```